# Convert org.restlet.data.MediaType to com.google.common.net.MediaType

Tags: java, guava, restlet

I'm using restlet to implement a simple RESTful API, and  it is providing me with an `org.restlet.data.MediaType` as a ContentType. However, I am trying to use some other API which consumes a `com.google.common.net.MediaType` (from guava). What is the best way to convert between these two types?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you should be able to do:

```
MediaType guavaMediaType = MediaType.parse(restletMediaType.getName());
```